# highscore-api vs sponsorship

Tags: flash, api

my flash-game is almost finished but there is a (big?) problem:

At its current state my game uses mochileaderboards (mochi's scoring system) for displaying a highscore list. I didn't upload the game yet so the highscore list just shows crap because I just wanted to test if it works with my code. So far so good.

Now I read that when I want to upload it to sponsors I have to remove ANY mochi-api or other similar stuff because sponsors don't want to see any different logo except theirs.

But when I remove the scoring-system shall I remove the appropriate scoring-interface (score, submit, etc) as well? I just ask because without the scoring-system IMHO the game's interface looks a little bit boring.

Are there any other scoring api's available that I can use even when I submit it to sponsors so they don't get any crisis when they see it in my game? How do you handle this? I hope you know what I mean…

TIA

Comment: Most sponsors like Armorgames and Kongregate have their own scoring API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all (before the answer) I was strongly affiliated with Armor Games at a point (in 2006) as well as several other sponsors. Since then I have only dealt with this sort of issue giving advice to friends but was not involved directly with it.

Most sponsors have their own scoreboard, it's a feature very easily added in general.

In fact with basic understanding of PHP and SQL it is extremely easy to build, and cheat proof your scoreboard (google is full of tutorials, I would link you to one I wrote but I don't know which version of AS you're using).

Several other sites provide scoreboards, newgrounds, armorgames etc.

I would however do this AFTER sponsorship, since it is a feature really easy to implement. I'd just write mock methods now (like add to scoreboard, load scoreboard, update scoreboard) call them, but leave them empty until you choose a sponsor.

A mock method: A method you have not really written and does nothing, to fill in the code of later. Your best guess is to tell the sponsor in the distribution package that a scoring system will be integrated once you secure the sponsorship itself. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. What is a mock method? In my gaming interface I have some buttons (for the highscore-system) like submit, score, etc. etc. shall I remove them? Or just disable and grey-out those buttons and tell the sponsor in my distribution package that a scoring system can be integrated? I'm totally unaware about this topic because it's the first time that I publish a game...